# No Audio on macOS QuickTime MPEG-4 Video

Tags: audio, video, quicktime, mp4

I am wondering what can be preventing the Quicktime player from playing the audio track alongside a video.

The files I have are MPEG-4. When launched on macOS QuickTime, there is no sound. I tested quickly on an iPhone, and the audio is played when the same files are launched. On the same machine, the Elmedia Player also successfully produces the audio.

How can I troubleshoot why QuickTime is not being able to play the audio track?

Comment: after starting Quicktime, go to system preferences and click on the Sound preference and see what's selected.  Also, is the volume indicated on the QT window.

Comment: What version of macOS, and secondly, which version of QuickTime Player - v.7 or v10.x?

Comment: Is this all files, or just a particular group of files?

Comment: @benwiggy a particular group of files. MOV files play with sound.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Check what codec the audio uses in the file. Get Info, maybe.